# Query regarding Pyside

Tags: python, pyside

In the below mentioned example when I click on 'Help' submenu under 'View' menu multiple times its creating multiple windows. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

```
import sys
from PySide import Qt Gui
from PySide.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.menu_bar()

    def menu_bar(self):
        helpAction = QtGui.QAction('&Help', self)
        helpAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+H')
        helpAction.triggered.connect(self.add_helpWindow)
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('View')
        menu.addAction(helpAction)

    def add_helpWindow(self):
        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        window.setWindowTitle('New Window')
        window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app=QtGui.QApplication.instance()      
    if not app:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You help window is just a `QMainWindow`, which is not modal and there are no restrictions on the number that can exist. Hence why if you select the help option multiple times, you get multiple windows.

You likely want to use a [`QMessageBox`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html) which has its `modal` property set. While there is nothing forcing only one dialog to exist at a time, being modal means that the use can only interact with that window so long as it is open. Example:

```
from Pyside.QtGui import QMessageBox

def add_helpWindow(self):
    help_dialog = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Help', 'Some Help Text Here')
    help_dialog.setModal(True)
    return help_dialog.exec_()
```

You can also get a more generic dialog box using [`QDialog`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html), which is the parent class of `QMessageBox`.

If that's not the behavior you want, you'll need to manually track whether the user has opened that window before, and then connect a signal that is emitted when the user closes the help window to a slot that reset the existence tracker. Here is an example using a non-modal `QDialog`:

```
from Pyside.QtGui import QDialog    

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.menu_bar()

        self.help_open = False # Tracks if the help dialog is already open

    def help_closed(self):
        self.help_open = False

    ...

    def add_helpWindow(self):
        if not self.help_open:
            self.help_open = True
            help_dialog = QDialog(self)
            # Any other setup code here
            help_dialog.setModal(False)
            help_dialog.accepted.connect(self.help_closed)
            help_dialog.rejected.connect(self.help_closed)
            help_dialog.show()
```

Comment: @user3164132 does this solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer (click the checkbox next to the answer) so that future readers know it worked. If no, please explain why it does not work.